# Como hacer para que en un For se vaya almacenando un int en una variable y no se sobreescriba con cada ejecucion JAVA

Tags: java

Pasa que en una ventana de facturación intento almacenar el valor de la cantidad de veces que se desea un objeto y para obtener la decisión del usuario estoy usando un `Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Cuantos llevas?")` y pues bien a la primera ejecución todo bien pero en adelante cuando el cliente vuelve a elegir otro producto y escoge una cantidad se actualiza la cantidad en toda la tabla con la ultima cantidad que escogió el usuario

---

Este es el código:

```
package UIcafeyteria;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class UIcafeyteria extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel cafe;
    DefaultTableModel teria;

    public UIcafeyteria() {
        initComponents();
        this.cafe = (DefaultTableModel) tablaProd.getModel();
        this.teria = (DefaultTableModel) tablafac.getModel();

    }

    public void CalculoTabla() {
        //Para sumar el monto
        int suma = 0, total;
        for (int i = 0; i < tablafac.getRowCount(); i++) {
            int precio = (int) tablafac.getValueAt(i, 1);
            int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Cuantos llevas?"));
            //Suma+=precio;

            total = precio * cantidad;
            tablafac.setValueAt(cantidad, i, 2);
            tablafac.setValueAt(total, i, 3);
            suma += total;
            Monto.setText(Integer.toString(suma));
        }
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablafac = new javax.swing.JTable();
        Borrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Imprimir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Seleccionar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Monto = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablaProd = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jMenu1.setText("jMenu1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tablafac.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Producto", "Precio", "Cantidad", "Importe"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, true, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        tablafac.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tablafac.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tablafacMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablafac);
        if (tablafac.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            tablafac.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            tablafac.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            tablafac.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
            tablafac.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        }

        Borrar.setText("Borrar");
        Borrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BorrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Imprimir.setText("Imprimir");

        Seleccionar.setText("Seleccionar");
        Seleccionar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SeleccionarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Monto.setEditable(false);
        Monto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MontoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));
        jLabel1.setText("Cyber Cafe:  CafeyTeria.");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("");
        jLabel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(112, 55));

        tablaProd.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"cafe",  new Integer(20),  new Integer(1)},
                {"leche",  new Integer(15),  new Integer(1)},
                {"cafe con leche",  new Integer(35),  new Integer(1)},
                {"Pan",  new Integer(10),  new Integer(1)},
                {"Queso",  new Integer(35),  new Integer(1)},
                {"Jamon",  new Integer(25),  new Integer(1)},
                {"Mayonesa",  new Integer(13),  new Integer(1)}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Producto", "Precio", "Cantidad"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        tablaProd.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tablaProdMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tablaProd);
        if (tablaProd.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            tablaProd.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            tablaProd.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            tablaProd.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        }

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Mongolian Baiti", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Monto:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 523, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Seleccionar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(Borrar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(Imprimir)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(Monto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(4, 4, 4))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Seleccionar)
                    .addComponent(Borrar)
                    .addComponent(Imprimir)
                    .addComponent(Monto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void SeleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if (tablaProd.getSelectedRowCount() > 0) {
            int[] indice = tablaProd.getSelectedRows();
            for (int i : indice) {
                Object[] fila = new Object[cafe.getColumnCount()];
                for (int j = 0; j < fila.length; j++) {
                    fila[j] = cafe.getValueAt(i, j);
                }
                teria.addRow(fila);
            }
        }
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tablafac.getRowCount(); i++) {
            int costo = (int) tablafac.getValueAt(i, 1);
            total += costo;
            Monto.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        }
//para sumar
    CalculoTabla();
    }                                           

    /* public void suma(){
    int total=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<tablafac.getRowCount();i++){
    int costo=(int) tablafac.getValueAt(i,1);
    int cant= (int) tablaProd.getValueAt(i,2);
   int cantfac= (int) tablafac.getValueAt(i,2);
   int imp= costo*cantfac;
    total+=costo*cant;
    Monto.setText(Integer.toString(total));
    tablafac.setValueAt(imp, i, 3);
        }
    }

    public void importe(){
    for(int i = 0; i<tablafac.getRowCount();i++){
    int costo=(int) tablafac.getValueAt(i,1);
    int cant= (int) tablafac.getValueAt(i,2);
   int imp= costo*cant;
    tablafac.setValueAt(imp, i, 3);


        }
    }
     */
    private void BorrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if (tablaProd.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            // remove selected row from the model
            teria.removeRow(tablafac.getSelectedRow());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " La tabla esta vacia o no seleccionaste la columna a eliminar ");
        }
    }                                      

    private void MontoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                     

    private void tablafacMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getClickCount()==2){
            System.out.println("asdsd");
        }
    }

    private void tablaProdMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        mouseClicked(evt);

    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIcafeyteria.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIcafeyteria.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIcafeyteria.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIcafeyteria.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UIcafeyteria().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Borrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton Imprimir;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Monto;
    private javax.swing.JButton Seleccionar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablaProd;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablafac;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! de que tabla hablas? podes aclarar mejor donde esta tu problema?

Comment: Puedes ir metiendo el valor en un Array, en un Map o en cualquier otro objeto capaz de almacenar varios valores.